# Formula on visible cells only

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, visible

I'm trying to get the below formula to work on visible cells only after I filter out what isn't needed.

```
=MIN(IF(G7=G6,0,SUMIFS($P$6:$P$760,$A$6:$A$760,A6,$G$6:$G$760,G6)),$B$3)
```

The formula is checking to see if the line below has the same ID, if it does it places a zero and moves on. If it doesn't match it sums up the value in P that meet the date requirement in A and the ID requirement in G. If the number is less than what's in B3 enter the lesser number. If it's higher than what's in B3 then enter in B3.

Comment: Use [subtotal](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939), e.g. [this](http://superuser.com/questions/885159/excel-function-determine-if-a-cell-is-visible)

Comment: =SUBTOTAL(105,IF(G10=G9,0,SUMIFS($P$6:$P$760,$A$6:$A$760,A9,$G$6:$G$760,G9)),$B$3)      I tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you delete out the cells you do not need?  Is the issue that the formula is including all cells (not just visible)?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't delete out the cells that aren't needed, because at times they are needed and I need the formula to adapt to that.

Comment: yeah the formula includes all cells visible and non-visible.

Comment: So you want the formula to be in all the cells but to change the returned value based on the visible cells only when it is filtered.  So if the actual row beneath is hidden then it uses the first non hidden row?

Comment: This may help: http://superuser.com/a/438877/547746

Comment: yeah Scott correct that's what I'm looking for.